# Querying record in a single partition very slow

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I have a large table (over 2 billion records) which is partitioned. Each partition contains roughly 500 million records. I have recently moved from physical hardware to AWS, i used a `mysqldump` to backup and restore the MySQL data. I have also recently created a new partition (`p108`). Querying data from old partitions (created on the old server) are running as normal, very quick, returning data in seconds. However querying records in the newly created partition (`p108`) is very slow - minutes.

`show create table` results

```
CREATE TABLE `termusage` 
  ( 
     `id`            BIGINT(20) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     `terminal`      BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `date`          DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, 
     `dest`          VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `feattrans`     BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `cost_type`     TINYINT(4) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `cost`          DECIMAL(16, 6) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `gprsup`        BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `gprsdown`      BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `duration`      TIME DEFAULT NULL, 
     `file`          BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `custcost`      DECIMAL(16, 6) DEFAULT '0.000000', 
     `invoice`       BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '99999999', 
     `carriertrans`  BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `session_start` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, 
     `session_end`   DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, 
     `mt_mo`         VARCHAR(4) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `grps_rounded`  BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `gprs_rounded`  BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `country`       VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `network`       VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `ctn`           VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `pricetrans`    BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `invoice`), 
     KEY `idx_terminal` (`invoice`, `terminal`), 
     KEY `idx_feattrans` (`invoice`, `feattrans`), 
     KEY `idx_file` (`invoice`, `file`), 
     KEY `termusage_carriertrans_idx` (`carriertrans`), 
     KEY `idx_ctn` (`invoice`, `ctn`), 
     KEY `idx_pricetrans` (`invoice`, `pricetrans`) 
  ) 
engine=innodb 
auto_increment=17449438880 
DEFAULT charset=latin1 
/*!50500 PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(invoice) 
(PARTITION p103 VALUES LESS THAN (621574) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
 PARTITION p104 VALUES LESS THAN (628214) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
 PARTITION p106 VALUES LESS THAN (634897) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
 PARTITION p107 VALUES LESS THAN (649249) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
 PARTITION p108 VALUES LESS THAN (662763) ENGINE = InnoDB, 
 PARTITION plast VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

I created the partition `p108` using the following query

```
ALTER TABLE termusage reorganize partition plast 
INTO        ( partition p108 VALUES less than (662763), 
              partition plast VALUES less than maxvalue )
```

I can see the file `termusage#p#p108.ibd` and looks to be "normal" and the data is there as i can get results from the query.

`information_schema.PARTITIONS` shows the following for the table - which indicates there is some kind of issue

```
Name    Pos Rows        Avg Data Length Method
p103    1   412249206   124 51124371456 RANGE COLUMNS
p104    2   453164890   133 60594061312 RANGE COLUMNS
p106    3   542767414   135 73562849280 RANGE COLUMNS
p107    4   587042147   129 76288098304 RANGE COLUMNS
p108    5   0           0   16384       RANGE COLUMNS
plast   6   0           0   16384       RANGE COLUMNS
```

How can i fix the partition ?

### Updated

Explain for good query

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, SIMPLE, t, p107, ref, idx_terminal,idx_feattrans,idx_file,idx_ctn,idx_pricetrans, idx_terminal, 17, const,const, 603, 100.00, Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Explain for poor query

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, SIMPLE, t, p108, ALL, idx_terminal,idx_feattrans,idx_file,idx_ctn,idx_pricetrans, , , , 1, 100.00, Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: Can you post explain output off comperable queries which queries the old and the new partition..

Comment: Make sure it's `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT...` so the output includes the field that shows which partition(s) it reads.

Comment: Added - and that indicates another issue - im running a `alter table check partition` again partition `p108` Im hoping to get some meaningful output from that

Comment: @RaymondNijland added

Comment: Okay that confirms that it's doing partition pruning, and not accidentally reading all the partitions. The EXPLAIN also shows that it's reading a trivial number of rows. It says 1 row, but that's probably a rounding error from 0 which is how many rows are in p108 according to your information_schema query. This is a mystery...

Comment: @BillKarwin Do you think a partition rebuild would resolve the issue ? or perhaps a server restart - im running a check partition at the moment - been running 30 minutes

Comment: Then next thing I'd try is enabling the [profiler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-profile.html) and run your long-running query again. Find out which stage is taking so long.

Comment: I don't have enough information to know whether rebuilding the table or the partition would help. It's odd that your check partition has been running 30 minutes on a partition with 0 rows.

Comment: @BillKarwin i dont think the partition has 0 rows - the file (file per partition is enabled) is 170GB ... i just think that somehow the information on where the information is stored is lost / corrupt

Comment: "Using temporary; Using filesort" this combination can be "fatal" for performance also in general you should try avoiding this combination because it can really hog up the MySQL server.. MySQL first will create a RAM temporary table to process the results.. if the settings are to low MySQL to hold all the data.. MySQL will covert that RAM temporary table into a disk based temporary table and use the quicksort algoritme on it... Besides you can't trust the rows in the explain for the InnoDB engine these are estimated,

Comment: Can you run `ALTER TABLE termusage ANALYZE PARTITION p108` to make sure the table and index stats are fresh. Then try your query against information_schema and your EXPLAIN again.

Comment: @BillKarwin ok will run that now. Check partition finished with `OK`. ran for 1 hour 39 mins

Comment: @BillKarwin `ALTER TABLE termusage ANALYZE PARTITION p108` took 0.33 seconds and has fixed the issue - both queries return the same explain results and the records are returned instantly

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for the pointer - my main issue is the size of server required to ensure that the tables / indexes can be loaded into Memory - i have 5 partitions at about 180GB each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers, the issue was resolved by running `ALTER TABLE ... ANALYZE PARTITION p108`.

The table and index statistics that guide the optimizer to choose the best way to read the table were out of date. It's common to use ANALYZE to make sure these statistics are updated after a significant data load or delete.

Comment: Thanks for your help